# grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider ClientCredentials filter no processing /oauth/token

Tags: grails, spring-security, oauth-2.0, grails-2.0

Trying to use grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider in grails 2.2.4. The authorize flow is working but when re-submitting the code in order to get a token (via /myapp/oauth/token) I was expecting ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter to authenticate the POST request but it does not. I see it in the filter chain.

Also, will it use the id/secret from my defined client in Config.groovy? It seems like it will try my DaoAuthenticationProvidor first and fail and go straight to the exception filter (and redirect to login endpoint).

```
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /oauth/token at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /oauth/token at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter'
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /oauth/token at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
```

My config:

```
        oauthProvider {               
            clients = [
                    [
                            clientId:"test",
                            clientSecret:"testSecret",
                            authorizedGrantTypes:["authorization_code"],
                            registeredRedirectUri:["http://myapp/other/"]
                    ]
            ]

        providerNames = [
                'samlAuthenticationProvider',
                'daoAuthenticationProvider',
                'anonymousAuthenticationProvider',
                'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider',
                'clientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider']
...
                '/oauth/authorize.dispatch':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
                '/oauth/token.dispatch':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
```

Url posted:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/oauth/token
grant_type=authorization_code
client_id=test
client_secret=testSecret
code=<the code I got from authorization>
redirect_uri=http:localhost:8080//myapp/other"
```

Comment: Is the order of the provider names correct? The order is important and as per documentation clientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider must be the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Is the redirect uri the same in all your requests?